# Anyone know how to covert a signed bitvector to signed int in Z3?

Tags: z3, smt, reliability

```html
(>  (bv2int (bvxor ((_ int2bv 32) x1) ((_ int2bv 32) y1))) 0)
```

x1 and y1 is two signed int, and after the xor. How can i convert them back as a signed int?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int2bv` and `bv2int`, but for the most part, those functions will be treated as uninterpreted (see e.g. the [API doc](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga5d2d89ecfad30793ad12a2aee1b139f5)). If you need the actual semantics, you will have to implement them yourself. It's not at all hard (just a big sum over if-then-elses of `2^i*x1[i]` terms), but the constraints you obtain this way are highly non-linear, so it's likely that the integer theory will give up and return unknown. See for instance [Z3 Performance with Non-Linear Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511503/z3-performance-with-non-linear-arithmetic), [How does Z3 handle non-linear integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic), and [Z3 : Questions About Z3 int2bv?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z3+int2bv).